# Compound Interest calculator isn't giving me correct data?

Tags: java

I have a compound interest calculator, but when I run the code and input the following numerals when it asks for it:

Principal: 10000
Rate: 0.02
Years:10

and choose "Annual" which is already set up so that if I or a user enters that particular string, the choice variable will automatically become 1 (or the other values already set if I enter the word Quarterly or Monthly). However, I'm supposed to be getting a value of: $12189.94 and am instead getting a value of:10200.0
Where am I doing wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class CompoundInterest {

public static void main (String [] args)
        { 
            Scanner cool = new Scanner (System.in);
double saving, rate;
int principal, years;
int choice;

System.out.println("Please enter you principal investment:");
/*Print statment prompts user to enter their principal investment*/
principal = cool.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Would you like to have a regular investment plan?");
/* Print out statement asks user if they would like to participate in a regular investment plan*/
String question =cool.next();

System.out.println("Please enter the number of years that you wish to invest for:");
/* Print statement prompts user to enter the number of years that they wish to invest for*/
years = cool.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter the return rate per year:");
/* Print statement prompts user to enter the return rate per year*/
rate = cool.nextDouble();

 System.out.println("What type of investment plan would you prefer (Annual, Quarterly, or Monthly)?");
String quest =cool.next();

 if ("Annual".equalsIgnoreCase(quest))
{ choice =1;

 }
 else if ("Quarterly".equalsIgnoreCase(quest)){
     choice = 4;
 }
 else if ("Monthly".equalsIgnoreCase(quest)){
     choice = 12;
 }
 else {
     choice = 0;
     System.out.println("Please choose a investment plan or speak to a financial advisor.");
 }

saving = principal*(1+(rate/choice))*Math.pow(choice,years);
System.out.println(saving);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for providing suggestions. It just seemed that I needed to use:

```
saving = principal * Math.pow(1+(double) (rate/ (choice)), choice * years);
```

In order for my equation to work as it seems my equation wasn't properly taking into consideration my integer values as saving is categorized as a double.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for calculating interest is incorrect. It should be:

```
saving = principal*Math.pow(1+(rate/choice), choice*years);
```

See the correct formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Periodic_compounding

Comment: The formula I'm using is one that was provided with by my professor for this code that I had to create and one that I have to specifically use. Plus I checked it beforehand by hand and with a calculator and got the value that I'm supposed to be getting. But when I run the code that specific result doesn't get churned out.

Comment: You may have implemented your professor's formula incorrectly. The code in your example is calculating: `10000*(1+(0.02/1))*(1^10) = 10200`. You want to do `10000*((1+(0.02/1))^(1*10)) = 12189`. Try the code I provided and see if it works.

Comment: Tried it, however it's still giving me the wrong output.

Comment: What output are you getting? I just tested it and it gives the exact output you wanted.

Comment: I'm still getting an output of 10200.0

Comment: Well did you recompile your code? You should be getting the correct output if you changed the code and recompiled it.

Comment: Yes, I recompiled the code and got the same outcome.

Comment: I'm sure you understand that by changing that line of code you should be getting a different output since it's a completely different calculation. You should be getting something different but you keep getting the same thing. Try it in an online IDE: https://ideone.com/RBuT1X

Comment: Don't know why you keep getting the same thing, try creating a totally new file and copy everything in from scratch.

Comment: Did that but still retained the same outcome.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, you can see from this link it works: https://ideone.com/RBuT1X